# Laravel - In Container.php line 879: Target class [\App\Helpers\SMS\Gateway\] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, lumen, laravel-artisan

I was trying to setup my Laravel lumen project in local. When i run `php artisan key:generate` command the following error occured and later none of the artisan commands is working. Checked the name space it is correct.

```
In Container.php line 879:

  Target class [\App\Helpers\SMS\Gateway\] does not exist.  


In Container.php line 877:
                                                  
  Class \App\Helpers\SMS\Gateway\ does not exist
```

I couldn't find this Container.php file anywhere.

Comment: have you executed composer install?

Comment: Yes I have done already. Tried composer update too